# Circle CI can't add project and it's not present in workflow either

Tags: continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, circleci, circleci-2.0

I got invited to a circle ci account but can't add any projects, it shows:

```
Contact repo admin
```

One reason can be because it's already added, but it's not visible in my workflow tab as well. How can I access the project and build it ?

Answer (score 0):

Please contact CircleCI Support. This isn't really a SO question.